# Constructing a new function $F(x)$ and apply Rolle's Theorem

Tags: analysis, derivatives, rolles-theorem

[image]

I have tried to construct a new function $F(x)$ such that $F(a)=F(b)=0$ and apply Rolle's Theorem, but the question is: there's two variables $f(c)$ and $g(c)$ on the rate of change (left-hand side) that I am concerned at. So how do I construct it?

Comment: This is Cauchy’s mean value theorem. Try shifting $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ then scaling to get functions that agree at the endpoints. Take their difference and you are in.

Comment: @CharlieFrohman Careful. Is it exactly Cauchy's MVT?

Comment: This is not an ordinary Cauchy's MVT, so I could not find the constructed function $F(x)$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my attempt and it's correct I think.

[image]

Comment: Your $F$ is not always defined.

Comment: What if let $F(x)=[f(x)-f(a)][g(x)-g(b)]$, then it is defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, that would give the correct answer.